# Selected lines with pattern: Vim Visual Mode

Tags: vim, neovim

I would like to select (in Vim) the lines that start with the same pattern. For example, if I have this:

```
if (...) {
    print "Accepted\n"
    o.attr_out = "Accepted";
}
else if (...) {
    print "Partially accepted\n"
    o.attr_out = "Partially Accepted";
}
else if (...) {
    print " NOT Accepted\n"
    o.attr_out = "Not Accepted";
}
```

Skip to this in a quick way in Vim.

```
if (...) {
    if (debug == true) print "Accepted\n"
    o.attr_out = "Accepted";
}
else if (...) {
    if (debug == true) print "Partially accepted\n"
    o.attr_out = "Partially Accepted";
}
else if (...) {
    if (debug == true) print " NOT Accepted\n"
    o.attr_out = "Not Accepted";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the vim command:

`:%s/print "/if ( debug == true ) &/g`

here's a quick breakdown of the command:

`%` - include all lines in the search

`s` - substiture the 1st pattern with the 2nd.

`/print "/` - the pattern you're searching for.

`if ( debug == true ) &/` - the text you want to replace the pattern with (note `&` will put back the `print "` text that it found in the search).

`g` - replace all occurrences on the same line. (Technically you don't need that here - since there's only one occurrence of `print "` on each line).

Refer to the `:help :s` command for more information.

Comment: Could you add `:help ...` references? Also the `/g` is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Hi, I was aware of the replace option in Vim, but I'm afraid it doesn't fix my problem, since this will change it for all the "prints" in the file. Instead, I only want to do it for those that are between a certain number of lines (for example, between 50 and 87), without modifying the other prints that are in the file.
Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Replace `%` with `50,87` and it'll only apply the search and replace to those lines.

Comment: @FAFernández, please don't move the goal post. You asked for "the lines" without further requirements, which makes this is a perfect answer for the question as you asked it.

Comment: @romainl it's right. I will try to be more explicit in the future.

Comment: @cguk70 Thanks for the tip, it will help me a lot in the future.